# Split an array into four sub-array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

> Given an array, it contains N element, which are all positive integers; if we can  find **three** elements, and they divide the array into four parts (**Notice: the three elements are not contained in any part of the four**), and the sum of each part are equal, then we call the array a "balanced" array. Design an algorithm to judge whether an array is balance, with limit: Time O(N), Space O(N).

Here is an example:

```
a = [1,7,4,2,6,5,4,2,2,9,8];
b = [1,8,10,5,3,1,2,3]
```

a is balanced, 'cause the element 4, 5, 9 divide the array into `[1,7], [2,6], [4,2,2], [8]`, the sum of each is 8.
`b` is not balanced, because we can not find a solution.

Any idea is appreciated!

Comment: Where are you stuck ?

Comment: I do not know how to solve it with O(N) time

Comment: You don't know the logical process, or have you found problems implementing it in your code ?

Comment: the logical process

Comment: Can you find the index of the element which divides the array into *two* equal-sum parts? If so, do that, then divide each of the parts in the same way. Remember, O(n) doesn't mean a single pass over the array, it means a constant number of single passes.

Comment: @AndyTurner Notice that the split elements is not contained in the sub array, I'm afraid your method do not work...

Answer (score 0):

### Hints

Consider the first element to be removed.

Once you know this position, you can compute the size of the first part.

Once you know the size of the first part, you can compute the location of the second element to be removed, and so on (because all elements are positive integers).

Now you need to find a way to perform this in O(N).  Try thinking about what you can do to reuse computations that have already been done, e.g. by keeping a rolling sum of the size of each of your parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this solution:

```
class BalancedArray
{

  public static void main( String[] args ) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
    int[] a = {      1, 7, 4, 2, 6, 5, 4, 2, 2, 9, 8   }; //BALANCED
    //int[] a = {7,0,6,1,0,1,1,5,0,1,2,2,2}; //BALANCED
    //int[] a = {1}; //NOT BALANCED
    int l = a.length;
    if ( l < 7 )
    {
      System.out.println( "Array NOT balanced" );
    } else
    {
      int maxX = l - 5;
      int maxY = l - 3;
      int maxZ = l - 1;
      int x = 1;
      int y = 3;
      int z = 5;
      int sumX = 0; //From 0 to x
      int sumY = 0; //From x to y
      int sumJ = 0; //From y to z
      int sumZ = 0; //From z to l

      for(x = 1; x < maxX; x++)
      {                       
        sumX = calcSum(a,0,x);

        for(y = x + 2; y < maxY; y++)
        {         
          sumY = calcSum(a,x+1,y);

          if(sumY != sumX){
            continue;
          }

          for(z = y + 2; z < maxZ; z++)
          {
            sumJ = calcSum(a,y+1,z);

            if(sumJ != sumY)
            {
              continue;
            }

            sumZ = calcSum(a,z+1,l);

            if(sumZ != sumJ){
              continue;
            }

            if(sumZ == sumX && sumX == sumY && sumY == sumJ)
            {
              System.out.println( "Array balanced!!! Elements -> X:" + x + " Y: " + y + " Z:" + z );
              return;
            }

          }
        }
      }

      System.out.println("Array NOT balanced!!");
    }
  }

  private static int calcSum(int[] src, int start, int end)
  {
    int toReturn = 0;
    for ( int i = start; i < end; i++ )
    {
      toReturn += src[i];
    }
    return toReturn;
  }
}
```

I made these assumptions:

1. between each of the three elements, which should split the array in 4 parts, there must be at least a distance of 2;
2. to be divided in 4 sub-arrays the source array must be at least 7 elements long;